# How To Use groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pipeline

I am trying to modify an html file in a Jenkins pipeline and I need to add a `span` tag.  In groovy I can do the following

```
def newNode = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { span {mkp.yield("$child")}}
```

where `child` is a string to put in the `span` tag.

When I tried to do this in a Jenkins Pipeline, I got an error related to a CPS mismatch so I added `@NonCPS` but I am now getting an error that says `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'span' found among steps`

I found this: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/ that talks about CPS mismatches.  I think it is basically trying to use the `span` tag as a DSL method, similar to `stage` or `steps`.  So is it possible to somehow use the `StreamingMarkupBuilder.bind()` function like I am trying to without Jenkins interpreting the `span` tag as a DSL method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a `Node` object separately.  So I used the following line:

```
def node = new groovy.util.Node(null, 'span', child)
```

Then I just appended that node to another node using the `append` function.